# Scipy nnls algorithm does not have termination tolerance option

Tags: python, scipy, spyder

I am using the nnls algorithm from scipy and am shocked to find that I cannot control the final tolerance, as can be done in Matlab using Tolx i.e, termination tolerance.

Modifying the Fortran code or even reading it is extremely hard. I am only new to python since a month.

I need to do $\| A x - b\|_2 \leq \epsilon\| b\|_2$(latex); How can I do this, other than write my own nnls! \epsilon is the tolerance!

I found another link that had to add an extra constraint, but that was an equality constriant!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lsq_linear` which is available in scipy version 0.17.

Comment: Wow, Thanks a lot. This definitely takes care of the tolerance(TolX).  There is another very cheap algorithm that you can write called sparse NNLS or sNNLS. This is what I used and was able to implement the constraint!